# Как отсортировать vector указателей на объекты пользовательского класса

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть класс `Student`, у которого есть параметр `st_name`, содержащий имя студента, которое присваивается во время объявления класса. Как я могу отсортировать список `vector`, который содержит экземпляры этих классов, используя имена студентов?

```
class Student {
private:
    string st_name;
public:
    Student(string name) {
        this->st_name = name;
    }
    string getName() {
        return st_name;
    }
};

class Example {
public:
    vector<Student*> students;

    void test() {
        students.push_back(new Student("Jolin"));
        students.push_back(new Student("Alan"));
        students.push_back(new Student("Kevin"));
        //TODO
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лишний  раз не копируйте строку:

```
class Student {
private:
    string st_name;
public:
    Student(const string& name) 
        : st_name(name) { }
    string getName()  const{
        return st_name;
    }
};

class Example {
    //функция сравнения
    static bool cmp(Student* p1, Student* p2)
    {
        return p1->getName() < p2->getName();
    }
public:
    vector<Student*> students;
    void test() {
        students.push_back(new Student("Jolin"));
        students.push_back(new Student("Alan"));
        students.push_back(new Student("Kevin"));
        //сортировка стандартным алгоритмом
        std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), cmp);
        //...
    }
};
```

И зачем держать в векторе указатели, а не объекты, не понятно? Не забывайте в деструкторе класса удалять все объекты под указателями.

Comment: хотя бы статической сделал `cmp()`... и раз уж к мелочам в абстрактном вопросе придираешься, то и в `getName()` возвращай ссылку... а ещё последние лет 9 все крутые ребята используют лямбды...

Comment: И я позанудствую :) - лучше `cmp(const Student* p1, const Student* p2)`, тем более что `getName()` - `const`.

Comment: Да и вообще если контейнер указателй я бы предложли boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp или хотябы в поинтер обернуть...

Comment: Ну, да,  если уж вдаваться в подробности, то много тем для занудства ..... Например,  лучше не в векторе хранить, а сразу в set

Comment: @Fat-Zer, верно, static  забыл дописать. Я не придирался, а сделал маленькую поправку , а вот  getName() не должен возвращать ссылку, иначе зачем поле сделать закрытым?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так можно возвращать `const string&`.

Comment: @EOF, можно,    но часто это лишнее,  если есть вероятность, что  возвращаемый объект может где то использоваться и модифицироваться.  Можно(лучше) еще 
 объявить как  noexcept  и еще много чего можно(лучше)...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, конечно константную ссылку... и в `getName()` её возвращать практически обязательно... в противном случае это, во-первых, накладные расходы, а во-вторых дезинформирует того, кто просматривает интерфейс класса, сообщая, что имя студента должно быть конструируется на лету во время её вызова...

Comment: Лишний раз не копировать строку можно только так : `Student(string && name) : st_name(std::move(name)) { }`. Этот конструктор можно просто добавить.

Comment: Это уже будет называться  лишний раз не ссылаться, а не копировать.  При lvalue ссылке тоже не копируется